# How to change BabylonJS HTML viewer background?

Tags: html, babylonjs

I am using the BabylonJS viewer to show a 3D (gltf) model on a website. However, since I have no prior experience using it, and I only need it to show this model, I am using the generic viewer (and I followed [this](https://doc.babylonjs.com/extensions/the_babylon_viewer) tutorial).

Now, I need to change the background color of the "minimal" configuration, which by default is dark blue. Is there any easy way to do this?

**Clarification: I am talking about the skybox color**

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to change your ***scene*** after creating it :) 
that would be ***RGBA colors***, for you to choose

```js
    scene.clearColor = new BABYLON.Color4(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to use scene.clearColor parameters (in DOM configuration).
Below is the code for Babylon Viewer with white scene color.

```
     <babylon extends="minimal">
    <model url="https://models.babylonjs.com/TrailMeshSpell/spellDisk.glb">

    </model>
    <camera>
        <behaviors>
            <auto-rotate type="0"></auto-rotate>
        </behaviors>
      <position x="3" y="3" z="3"></position>
    </camera>
    <scene>
<clear-color r="1" g="1", b="1"></clear-color>
   </scene>
</babylon>
```

Another example is here - https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/how-to-use-scene-clearcolor-parameters-with-babylon-viewer/5266

Answer (score 0):

for json configuration

```
"scene": {
    "clearColor": {
        "r": 1,
        "g": 1,
        "b": 1
    }
}
```